# 7-zip: Extracting archive to a custom folder structure

Tags: 7-zip

Given an archive with the following structure:

```
archive.zip
|-- v7.5
    |-- install
        |-- app-7.5
            |-- file1
            |-- file2
            |-- file3
```

Using 7zip I'd like to extract only the contens of folder `app-7.5` to the directory `C:\app` while keeping any folder structure below this folder. This is my current command:

```
7z.exe x archive.zip -oC:\app -aoa -r app-7.5
```

But this generates a structure like this:

```
C:\app
|-- archive
    |-- v7.5
      |-- install
          |-- app-7.5
              |-- file1
              |-- file2
              |-- file3
```

Whereas I want:

```
C:\app
  |-- file1
  |-- file2
  |-- file3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't insist on the *command form*, you may use the *graphical user interface* - the file

```
7zfm.exe
```

(which is installed with `7z`).

You may then display 2 panels and there will be no problem to unpack *only part* of the 7-zip folder structure - the procedure is identical (and seems to be) with *copying selected folders and / or files*.